# Multiple Vue 3 watchers & Typescript ... how to use?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vetur

N.B. I'm using the `@vueuse/core` library to obtain some values for the below example, but I believe knowledge of the library for this question is moot.

I have the following triple watcher:

```
// Reactive Mouse Positionining
const { x, y } = useMouse()

//  Detect if the Mouse has been pressed:
const { pressed } = useMousePressed({ 
  target: celestiaSkyViewerRoot, 
  touch: true 
})

watch([pressed, x, y], ([newPressed, newX, newY], [prevPressed, prevX, prevY]) => {
  if (showConstellations.value) {
    if (!newPressed && newX !== prevX) {
      activeConstellation.value = getActiveConstellation(newX, newY)
    }
  }

  dragging.value = pressed.value

  if (newPressed && newX !== prevX) {
    azimuthalOffset.value -= (newX - prevX) / 6
  }
})
```

However, I am seeing the following Typescript errors occur:

For `newX`, relating to the line: `activeConstellation.value = getActiveConstellation(newX, newY)`

```
Argument of type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

For `newX`, relating to the line: `azimuthalOffset.value -= (newX - prevX) / 6`

```
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

However, Vetur is only showing an issue for `newY`, relating to the line: `azimuthalOffset.value -= (newX - prevX) / 6`:

```
The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

Does anyone know a possible solution for this? Essentially, these errors are stopping a reload of my dev server ... and it's very much becoming a frustrating development bottle neck ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone gets stuck with this like I did, this is the following solution without the need to check any types as per the above answer:

```
watch([pressed, x, y] as const, ([newPressed, newX, newY], [_, prevX, prevY]) => {
   ... // do something here
})
```

So, you just need to cast the Vue 3 watcher multiple array: `[] as const`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the type definitions for the function and you didn't provide a working example so I just have to guess:

The errors say that `newX`,`newY`,`prevX`,`prevY` have the type `number | boolean` but I can't tell you why. The way your code is written, you expect them to be `number` only.

**Three solutions that all have slightly different behavior, but they should all get typescript to compile:**

Do not execute further if any of the variable are not `number`:

```js
watch([pressed, x, y], ([newPressed, newX, newY], [prevPressed, prevX, prevY]) => {
  if (typeof newX !== 'number' || typeof newY !== 'number' ||
      typeof prevX !== 'number' || typeof prevY !== 'number') return;
  if (showConstellations.value) {
  ...
```

Use a default value if a variable is not of type `number`:

```js
watch([pressed, x, y], ([newPressed, newX, newY], [prevPressed, prevX, prevY]) => {
  if (typeof newX !== 'number') newX = 0;
  if (typeof newY !== 'number') newY = 0;
  if (typeof prevX !== 'number') prevX = 0;
  if (typeof prevY !== 'number') prevY = 0;
  if (showConstellations.value) {
  ...
```

Force those variables to be `number`. If any of those variable actually can be a `boolean` (I am not sure), then in that case this will lead to unexpected behavior:

```js
watch([pressed, x, y], ([newPressed, newX, newY], [prevPressed, prevX, prevY]) => {
  ...
    activeConstellation.value = getActiveConstellation(newX as number, newY as number);
  ...
    azimuthalOffset.value -= ((newX as number) - (prevX as number)) / 6
```